# Проверка аргумента, который передается функции

Tags: javascript, валидация, объекты

```
function showWarning(options) {
  var width = options.width || 200; // по умолчанию
  var height = options.height || 100;
  var contents = options.contents || "Предупреждение";
}
showWarning({
  contents: "Вы вызвали функцию" // и всё понятно!
});
```

Как проверить, что аргумент, который передается в функцию является объектом?

Answer (score 1):

Объектом в JS является многое, так что это довольно общая проверка.
Можно так сделать:

```js
function test(config){
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(config).toLowerCase() === '[object object]'){
    console.info(`${JSON.stringify(config)} - объект!`);
  }else{
    console.info(`${config} - что-то иное, не объект :)`);
  }
}

test(42);
test(_ => 42);
test({0: 42});
```

Comment: не удивлюсь, если автор вообще просил: `if (options != null)`

Comment: @Grundy, мы тут добру учим, а не писать код индусов :)

Comment: а где тогда пример с деструктуризацией? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, учить, а не сводить с ума новичка, у которого голова лопнет от разнообразия :) Кстати, а что с ней?

Comment: как-то так: `function showWarning({width:width=10,height:height=20}) {`

Comment: @Grundy, (1) Это не проверка, хотя, конечно, удобно. (2) Оборачивать в `try...catch` каждый вызов функции? Если вызвать `fn(null)` или `fn(undefined)`, то будет `TypeError`.

Comment: ага, это проблема с ним :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showWarning(options) {
  if (typeof options == "object" && options != null) {
    console.log("Является объектом");
  } else {
    console.log("Не является объектом");
  }
}
```

Comment: `typeof null` _внезапно_ - `"object"`

Comment: @Grundy, так ли внезапно?

Comment: @Other, вообще говоря да:)

Comment: @Grundy, Вы, случаем, не знаете отчего не пофиксили это? На мой взгляд это баг, пусть хоть в строгом режиме пофиксят. Кстати, массивы тоже объектами считаются определяются вроде.

Comment: @Other, без понятия. Скорее всего, чтобы не сломать кучу скриптов, которые это могут как-то использовать. [typeof](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) возвращает object для всего кроме: undefined, function, symbol, и примитивов number, string, boolean

Comment: @Grundy, выходит очень сомнительный оператор, я скажу. Но разве нет строгого режима как раз для решения проблемы совместимости. Плюс, JS уже пора включить турбо-несовместимость. Пусть куча старого шлака уже не используется и не заставляет его хоть как-то поддерживать.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```
option.constructor == Object
```

Проверяет Object ли непосредственно функция конструктор или нет.

typeof возвращает 'object' и для массивов и для null.

Comment: У `null` вызов свойства выкинет ошибку.

Comment: Да, кстати.) Тогда твой вариант наилучший.

Comment: Фиксится, при желании, через `try...catch`. Правда зачем такие сложности? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(options === 'object' && options != null)
```